# I'm trying to get my While loop working with some scenarios? some help appreciated

Tags: sql, t-sql, while-loop

The Scenarios is as follows however my while loop keeps printing the files out twice for the first if statement.

2nd Scenario - Restoring Full and Diff
Logical Order: Full Backup with No Recovery and Diff With Recovery

3rd Scenario - Restoring Full and Logs
Logical Order: Full with No Recovery and Last Log with Recovery and logs                  before No Recovery

4th Scenario - Restoring Full, Diffs and Logs
Logical Order: Full with No Recovery and Latest Diff with No Recovery and logs            before last log No Recovery and Last Log with Recovery.

Last File needs to be in Recovery

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET 
  @Counter = 1 
  /*EXEC master..sp_executesql @FullBackupSQL */
  WHILE (
    @Counter <= (
      SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM 
        Files
    )
  ) BEGIN 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Files 
WHERE 
  @Counter = ID 
SET 
  @Counter = @Counter + 1 IF @DiffBackupFile IS NOT NULL 
  AND @FullBackupFile IS NOT NULL 
  AND @LogbackupFile IS NULL BEGIN 
SET 
  @FullBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + '  FROM DISK = ''' + @FullBackupFile + ''' WITH  NORECOVERY,  MOVE ''' + @DatabaseName + ''' TO ''' + @FullBackupFileCopy + ''', MOVE ''' + @FullBackupFileCopyldf + ''' 
 TO ''' + @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf + ''' , NORECOVERY,NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5' PRINT '139,' + @FullBackupSQL 
  /*EXEC master..sp_executesql @FullBackupSQL */
SET 
  @DiffBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @DiffBackupFile + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  RECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' PRINT '143,' + @DiffBackupSQL 
  /* EXEC master..sp_executesql @DiffBackupSQL */
SET 
  @Counter = @Counter + 1 END IF @FullBackupFile IS NOT NULL 
  AND @LogbackupFile IS NOT NULL 
  AND @DiffBackupFile IS NULL BEGIN 
SET 
  @FullBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + '  FROM DISK = ''' + @FullBackupFile + ''' WITH  NORECOVERY,  MOVE ''' + @DatabaseName + ''' TO ''' + @FullBackupFileCopy + ''', MOVE ''' + @FullBackupFileCopyldf + ''' 
 TO ''' + @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf + ''' , NORECOVERY,NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5' PRINT '152,' + @FullBackupSQL 
  /*EXEC master..sp_executesql @FullBackupSQL */
SET 
  @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @LogbackupFile + ''' WITH FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' PRINT '156,' + @LogBackupSQL 
  /*  EXEC master..sp_executesql @LogBackupSQL */
SET 
  @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @LogbackupFile + ''' WITH FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' PRINT '160,' + @LogBackupSQL 
  /*  EXEC master..sp_executesql @LogBackupSQL */
  END IF @FullBackupFile IS NOT NULL 
  AND @LogbackupFile IS NOT NULL 
  AND @DiffBackupFile IS NOT NULL BEGIN 
SET 
  @FullBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + '  FROM DISK = ''' + @FullBackupFile + ''' WITH  NORECOVERY,  MOVE ''' + @DatabaseName + ''' TO ''' + @FullBackupFileCopy + ''', MOVE ''' + @FullBackupFileCopyldf + ''' 
 TO ''' + @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf + ''' , NORECOVERY,NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5' PRINT '171,' + @FullBackupSQL 
  /*EXEC master..sp_executesql @FullBackupSQL */
SET 
  @DiffBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @DiffBackupFile + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' PRINT '175,' + @DiffBackupSQL 
  /* EXEC master..sp_executesql @DiffBackupSQL */
SET 
  @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @LogbackupFile + ''' WITH FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' PRINT '179,' + @LogBackupSQL 
  /*  EXEC master..sp_executesql @LogBackupSQL */
SET 
  @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @LogbackupFile + ''' WITH FILE = 1,  RECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' PRINT '183,' + @LogBackupSQL 
  /*  EXEC master..sp_executesql @LogBackupSQL */
SET 
  @Counter = @Counter + 1 END END
```

Comment: The `SELECT * FROM Files` appears to be irrelevant, the variables are not being set here. And you appear to be restoring the same log file twice. One option is to do all files `WITH NORECOVERY` and then just do a final `RESTORE DATABASE WITH RECOVERY`

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the loop and the `SELECT *` is entirely unclear: you aren't actually using the data from them anyway.

All you need to do is restore each part using `WITH NORECOVERY` then use a final `RESTORE WITH RECOVERY` to get the database online.

Note also

- `RESTORE` and `BACKUP` can be fully parameterized, there is no need for `sp_executesql`. And even if you did need it you must make sure to escape your names using `QUOTENAME`.
- Make sure your object names are `sysname` or `nvarchar(128)`, and your filenames are `nvarchar(255)`.
- You can also simplify the code by nesting your `IF` statements (you cannot restore a diff without a full backup anyway).
- `NOUNLOAD` is only relevant for `TAPE` devices.

```sql
IF @FullBackupFile IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    RESTORE DATABASE @DatabaseNameCopy
    FROM DISK = @FullBackupFile
    WITH NORECOVERY,
      MOVE @DatabaseName TO @FullBackupFileCopy,
      MOVE @FullBackupFileCopyldf TO @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf,
      NORECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 5;

     IF @DiffBackupFile IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RESTORE DATABASE @DatabaseNameCopy
        FROM DISK = @DiffBackupFile
        WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5;
    END;
END;

IF @LogbackupFile IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    RESTORE LOG @DatabaseNameCopy
    FROM DISK = @LogbackupFile
      WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5
END;

RESTORE DATABASE @DatabaseNameCopy
WITH RECOVERY;
```

If you need to loop through a list of files, the easiest way to do it is using a cursor.

```sql
DECLARE @crsr CURSOR;
SET @crsr = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT Filename
    FROM Files;

OPEN @crsr;

FETCH NEXT @crsr INTO @LogbackupFile;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    RESTORE LOG @DatabaseNameCopy
    FROM DISK = @LogbackupFile
      WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5

    FETCH NEXT @crsr INTO @LogbackupFile;
END;
```